# SQL and php array(). Elegant method to guarantee query order after arbitrary insertion order/update

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am pulling an array of line items from an invoice:

```
private function lineItemsFromInvoice($xeroInvoice) : array
{
    $lineItems = array();
    foreach($xeroInvoice[XeroKeys::_XERO_INVOICE_KEY_LINE_ITEMS] as $value) {
        array_push($lineItems, $value);
    }
    return $lineItems;
}
```

Following this, they are being inserted into a DB via:

```
foreach($this->lineItems() as $invoiceLineItem) {
    ...some SQL INSERT STATEMENT
}
```

I need to be able to query the line items and keep them in the order they were inserted.  Further, **the invoice itself can be updated, and line items inserted at any arbitrary position in the array.  This order the items are sorted in the query needs to reflect this**.

I could use a time stamp and `ORDER BY` and ensure that each line item is updated every time the `INSERT` statement is run.

I could also use an `$index = 0` and `$index++` in the `lineItemsFromInvoice()` function and add a `Key => Value` pair to the array and insert that as part of each `LineItem` but this seems messy.  I don't know about an `array()` with:

`Array(LineItem, 'Order' => '0', LineItem, 'Order' => '1' ...)`

Are these solutions typical and/or viable?  What would commonly be seen in a production environment?

Comment: You've provided two valid solutions that are typical ways to solve this problem.  Are you asking for an opinion of which is better?

Comment: I don't have the confidence or experience to know if they're valid, or typical.  You've just given me a little boost though.  This is the first time I've ever had to solve a problem like this.  I've edited my question -thank you.

Comment: Your mysql table should have a primary key which is an integer type column that auto-increments. This primary key is unique so this way you can guarantee that no line items have the same id. You can use this to sort.

Comment: With timestamp, you can't be sure that two line items were not inserted at the same second if you are inserting records sequentially.

Comment: @KodosJohnson That won't work.  I cannot guarantee the order of insertion.  Invoices can be edited.  A line item might be added to the top of an invoice at a later time, and will be inserted with the highest primary key value.

Comment: @MattS I've just tested the timestamp and the items are inserted at identical times to the millisecond.

Comment: I would add an order column to the table and array because it's guaranteed to always work.  You are programmatically defining the order.

Comment: You mean invoices will be edited before insertion? Then the top line item will have the lowest primary key. If you mean it will be edited after insertion, then what happens with the already-inserted line items? They will still have a lower order whether you do timestamp or your `$index` method.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Invoices can be arbitrarily edited, after insertion.  Customers frequently add, remove, or customise items.  Customisations are added as additional line items proceeding the particular product.  I mentioned this.  I put it in bold text.  The already inserted items are updated if they are modified.

Comment: In that case, I would say your `$index` method should be fine. Another option is - if you keep track of each invoice with an invoice id - you can completely wipe all line items belonging to a certain invoice id (i.e. `DELETE * FROM lineitems WHERE invoiceid = :theid`) before processing them. In you go this route, my primary key suggestion should work.

Comment: This is why I come to Stack Overflow.  Which would typically be used in a production environment?  I love this job.  I love that it's one problem after another.  I'm flying solo here so I really do depend of all of you.

Comment: I would go with adding the `$index` to the array. My suggestion was just an alternative. I have used it in production environments but it is a little more taxing on the database since you have to make one extra trip to delete all the existing records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the advice given by Matt S above, this is the implementation I will go with.

```
private function lineItemsFromInvoice($xeroInvoice) : array
{
    $lineItems = array();
    $index = 0;
    foreach($xeroInvoice[XeroKeys::_XERO_INVOICE_KEY_LINE_ITEMS] as $value) {
        $value["index"] = $index;
        array_push($lineItems, $value);
        $index++;
    }
    return $lineItems;
}
```

The question is now can I guarantee a php array() will add the `["index"]` keys at the end?

Comment: Is `$value` an array? In that case, you should set the `index` key of each `$value`, not the `$lineItems` set, since `$value` is the variable that represents each line item. Also, you didn't increment the $index variable.  Here is my suggested change: `$value['index'] = $index++;array_push($lineItems, $value);`

Comment: $value IS an array().  Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget to do `$index++` at the end to increment $index on each iteration.